# Copy xml map from one workbook to another

Tags: xml, vba, excel

XML noob here with an inherited project.
Still reading ?  Thanks.

We have workbooks to collect accounting data from different entities.  The workbooks are completed & returned and then, in MS Access, an xml-based upload utility posts the data to a database.

Most workbooks work as expected, but there's a handful where one of the worksheets doesn't upload.  I've investigated and I can see the xml map is not defined for the problem worksheet.  Probably due to user copy/paste but not sure.

So I think, ok, simple, I'll export the xml map from a known good workbook, and import to the problem workbooks.  voila, xml mapping reset & complete.  wrong...

Have been wrestling with this a while now.  Primarily trying to leverage the code here
http://www.umid.info/node/53
which seems to "want" to work but it's been one issue after another.  so no luck really.

At this point, I don't even know if my concept is valid.  Is this something that is doable ?  Most every website talks about exporting/importing *data*.  I want to export/import the xml *mapping*.   Any clues appreciated.  ps I do not have the .xsd file.

Thanks !

Comment: You state "I can see the xml map is not defined", so this seems to be an issue all within Excel... before it even gets to the MS Access "upload utility".  You probably do not need to tag this as ms-access?  I see that you're new to posting on Stack Exchange.  It is best to keep the question focused.  If you have problems later with another part of the process, then research it separately and post another question focused on the new issue.  You can edit your posted question to refine the tags and the wording.

Comment: See [How to copy xml mapping from one workbook to another workbook?](http://www.umid.info/node/53)